# Performance hit when selecting dynamic menu items for an Excel custom UI

Tags: vba, excel, ribbon

I have stitched together an Excel workbook that dynamically populates some custom UI drop down menus.

Here's the code that populates the menu

```
Sub GetFilterByTeam(Control As IRibbonControl, ByRef content)

content = "<menu xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui""><button id=""Team1"" label=""Team1"" onAction=""FilterTeam""/><button id=""Team2"" label=""Team2"" onAction=""FilterTeam""/><button id=""Team3"" label=""Team3"" onAction=""FilterTeam""/><button id=""Team4"" label=""Team4"" onAction=""FilterTeam""/><button id=""Team5"" label=""Team5"" onAction=""FilterTeam""/><button id=""Team6"" label=""Team6"" onAction=""FilterTeam""/></menu>"

End Sub
```

When I select any value in the dynamicMenu a macro is fired.  The macro grabs the ID of dynamic button

Here's that code

```
Sub FilterTeam(ByRef Control As IRibbonControl)

    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets("Filter").ListObjects("FilterTable").DataBodyRange.Rows.Delete

    Call AddToFilterList(ParamTeamName:=Replace(Control.ID, "_", Chr(32)))
    Call Filter

End Sub
```

Short explanation of the above

1. On Error to skip over the errors is the table "Filter" is already empty
2. AddToFilter explained below
3. Filter just runs an advancedfilter macro on the main table with criteria in the table populated by AddToFilter

Here's the problem.

Performance is great with the first item in the dynamicMenu.  Rounds down to 0 milliseconds.  However, the other buttons in the dynamicMenu have performance on the order of 200 milliseconds.

By measuring the calls, I identified that the

```
Call AddToFilterLists(....
```

Part is what's causing.  I've tried passing a simple string (for testing purposes) instead of control.ID but that doesn't help

I am at a lose.  I think I'm making a small mistake but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Here's the code for AddToFilterList

```
Sub AddToFilterList( _
    Optional Param1 As String = "", _
    Optional Param2 As String = "", _
    Optional Param3 As String = "", _
    Optional Param4 As String = "", _
    Optional Param5 As String = "", _
    Optional Param6 As String = "", _
    Optional Param7 As String = "", _
    Optional Param8 As String = "", _
    Optional Param9 As String = "", _
    Optional Param10 As String = "", _
    Optional Param11 As String = "", _
    Optional Param12 As String = "", _
    Optional Param13 As String = "", _
    Optional Param14 As String = "")

    Dim LO As ListObject
    Dim oNewRow As ListRow

    Set LO = Sheets("Filter").ListObjects("FilterTable")

    Set oNewRow = LO.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)

    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, Column1).Value = Param1
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, Column2).Value = Param2
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, Column3).Value = Param3
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, Column4).Value = Param4
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, Column5).Value = Param5
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, Column6).Value = Param6
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, Column7).Value = Param7
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, Column8).Value = Param8
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, Column9).Value = Param9
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, Column10).Value = Param10
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, Column11).Value = Param11
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, Column12).Value = Param12

End Sub
```

Commenting out some of the oNewRow = lines helps but what I can't figure out is why the performance is dependent on which value I select in the dynamicMenu.  And that effect is very repeatable and quantifiable.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to "solve" the performance issue, but I worked around it by bringing the code into AddToFilterList into the FilterTeam sub.  The performance is consistent now.